# Address Information from street name

Tags: c#, regex

**What do I need:**

For the input:

```
Somestreet
Somestreet 12    
Somestreet 12 A    
Somestreet 12-14
```

output:

```
Somestreet

Somestreet | 12

Somestreet | 12 | A 

Somestreet | 12 | - | 14
```

where `|` is delimiter

**What I have done:**

```
var pattern = @"(\d+)";
var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var matchCollection = regex.Split(input);

var street = matchCollection[0];

if (matchCollection.Length > 1)
{
   houseNumber = matchCollection[1];
}

if (matchCollection.Length > 2)
{
   houseNumberLetter = matchCollection[2];
}
```

Its ok for the first three cases but not for number four.

Can you help me please?

Comment: did you want a newline between the strings? Is there any spaces after the letter `A` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I want to split tthe information in many parts. 1. For streetname, 2. for house number, 3. for house number with extra letter (if given). But if the input in form of "Streetname 12-14" I read only Streetname 12 and -

Comment: @AvinashRaj after letter A there can be spaces, but it will not be a problem, cause I check the strings after split with `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
string result = string.Join(" | ", Regex.Matches(input, @"(\w+|\-)").Cast<Match>().Select(d => d.Value));
```

**UPDATE**

Better?

```
string result = string.Join(" | ", Regex.Matches(input, @"([a-zA-Z\. ]+|[0-9]+|\-)").Cast<Match>().Select(d => d.Value.Trim()));
```

I had to separate letter and number matching to include possible spaces.

Comment: Thank you (\w+|\-) its works good. The only two problems are "." if the input is Some.street. How can I ignore points? And the second one is space before number. Example: Some street 34.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it next week and accept it if is the solution! :)